# Azure Data Factory - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-hdinsight

I created a linked service for creating an HDInsight cluster a few weeks back, was able to modify it after the fact as well for # nodes, cluster type, etc.

When I go to edit the HDInsight linked service today, it throws back "Maximum call stack size exceeded". I tried creating a fresh linked service today with the same parameters and I encounter the same error there.

I tried the same behavior on a different data factory under a different subscription and there it was successful, no errors were thrown. Then I tried it with a different linked service there, and saw the same error... Wondering if anybody has encountered this particular scenario and had insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issue should have been fixed. Please refresh the UI and try again. Thanks for the patience.

Comment: Thanks! Just verified and am now able to make changes I was previously not able to.